# color points based on what side of line they are on

Tags: math, vector, processing, vectormath

I am trying to make a little algorithm that colors a point a certain color based on what side of a line the point is on. This is what i have at the moment. The code doesnt give any errors, but the colors also arent correct for the dots.. Could someone point out to me what i am doing wrong?

See the code:

```
PVector[] points; 

void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
  points = new PVector[10];
  for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    points[i] = new PVector(random(0, width), random(0, height));
  }

  ExtremesLine(points);
}

void ExtremesLine(PVector[] pts) {
  float maxx = 0, minx = width+1;
  PVector min = new PVector(), max = new PVector();
  ArrayList<PVector> groupA = new ArrayList<PVector>(), groupB = new ArrayList<PVector>();
  for (int i = 0; i < pts.length; i++) {
    if (pts[i].x > maxx) { 
      maxx = pts[i].x;
      max = pts[i];
    } 
    if (pts[i].x < minx) {
      minx = pts[i].x;
      min = pts[i];
    }
  }
  PVector divisionLine  = new PVector();
  PVector.sub(max, min, divisionLine);
  PVector normal  = new PVector(-divisionLine.y, divisionLine.x).normalize();
  for (int i = 0; i < pts.length; i++) {
    float s = PVector.dot(normal, pts[i].copy().normalize());
    if ( s < 0) groupA.add(pts[i]);
    else if ( s > 0) groupB.add(pts[i]);
  }

  fill(0);
  line(min.x, min.y, max.x, max.y);
  for (int i = 0; i < groupA.size(); i++) {
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    ellipse(groupA.get(i).x, groupA.get(i).y, 10, 10);
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < groupB.size(); i++) {
    fill(0, 0, 255);
    ellipse(groupB.get(i).x, groupB.get(i).y, 10, 10);
  }
}
```

As you can see from the images below sometimes it works but 90% of the time it doesnt. First image is the correct result, second image is the incorrect result
[image]
[image]

If there is anything unclear pls let me know so i can clarify!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to dot with vectors from `min`:

replace

```
float s = PVector.dot(normal, pts[i].copy().normalize());
```

by

```
float s = PVector.dot(normal, pts[i].copy().sub(min).normalize());
```

and it will work as expected:

[image]

Tangentially, since `min` and `max` are Processing built-ins, are you sure that you want to use them as variable names?

Comment: didnt know about min and max being processing built-ins, thanks will change that :) could you maybe elaborate why i need to subtract `min` from the `pts[i]`?

Comment: There is this duality with vectors. On the one hand, they represent points, on the other hand they represent arrows (direction and magnitude). If you think of `pt[i]` as a *vector* -- implicitly it is the vector which goes from `(0,0)` to `pt[i]` -- the arrow from the upper left hand corner to the point. In effect, your original code has implicitly based on the angle between *that* vector and `normal` but what you really want would be based on the angle between `normal` and a vector which comes from `directionLine`